# Multiple _ga cookies on GA4

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager

I noticed there are 3 `_ga` cookies when I load my website. All of them have different client_ids and all of them set on different domains:

- one on my own shop's domain
- one on analytics.google.com
- one on reddit.com (I have reddit pixel)

I don't have multiple domains or even subdomains. Everything is set up on one domain. I'm on GA4.

Why do I get 3 different `client_id`? Isn't there supposed to be only ONE `_ga` cookie with ONE `client_id`? How to avoid this problem, because it messes up my stats? Where's my mistake?

Comment: Can you explain why it messed up with your stat? You GA report will only show the data from the client id with your domain. Other domain's GA cookie should not affect with yours.

Comment: Strangely it does not report data from my domain. I collect user's cliend_id on my order form to be able to track user's actions before purchase. I noticed that none of the IDs that my order form catches matches any of that are inside GA4 reports. So it must take client ID from a different _ga cookie...

Comment: Can you show us the code you grab the _ga cookie? Also the expect cookie and real cookie you have in your browser

Comment: Here's the value set by the _ga cookie with domain "mydomain.com": 
`GA1.1.979594187.1666180262`

Here's the value set by the _ga cookie with domain "analytics.google.com":
`GA1.3.1787514151.1656508983`

Here's the code that I use to extract the client_id from the _ga cookie:
`let gaClientID = document.cookie.match(/_ga=(.+?);/)[1].split('.').slice(-2).join('.');`

The value of gaClientID returns '979594187.1666180262', but there is no such ID in my GA4 reports, which makes me think it tracks only client_ids set from analytics.google.com domain

Comment: Actually it is doing good. The cookie you have is `GA1.1.979594187.1666180262` But the actual client id is `979594187.1666180262`.  So your variable `gaClientID` should be `979594187.1666180262` ? Can you tell me which field you are comparing in GA4 report?

Comment: Not quite sure I understand you correctly. But if you mean which "dimension" I choose to find that ID, it's the `Client ID` in the GA4 reports.